# wp_mail() - Sending 'file' input type from form as attachment

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email

I have shortcode that creates and validates a form in my fucntions.php file. After the form is submitted and validated, the data is then stored in SESSION variables. The SESSION variables are used to carry the information to a custom PHP template page. This page emails the form data using wp_mail() and displays a thank you note.

My issue is that the form has a 'file' input type for an image upload. I have it validated correctly, but transferring the uploaded image and then emailing it as an '$attachments" in the wp_mail() function is something I am struggling with.

Also I know I should save the uploaded image in a temp folder instead of storing it in a SESSION variable. And then I will just have to delete the image after the email is sent.

My question is HOW? The code for all of this is very long so here are the short and sweet versions:

functions.php (in a shortcode function)

```
<?php
$file = "";
$fileErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   //file upload is required, make sure its not empty
   if(empty($_FILES['pmFile'])){
       $fileErr = "This is required!";
   }
   else{
       $file = $_FILES['pmFile'];//I validate here, but lets just say its OK     
   } 

   //If the error message is empty, store data in SESSION variables, and 
   //uploaded file in temp folder + redirect to thank you page
   if(empty($fileErr)){

      //HOW DO I SAVE THE FILE TEMPORARILY FOR USE ON THE NEXT PAGE??? 

      wp_redirect( '../wp-content/themes/rest of the path/thankYouPage.php' );
      exit();

   }else{ /*display errors*/}

}

//down here is where I wrote the code for the form. YES method=post, YES I 
//included enctype="multipart/form-data, YES the file input name is in fact 
//'pmFile'.
?>
```

thankYouPage.php

```
//initial page stuff 
//start email setup
$to = 'XXXXX@gmail.com';

$email_from = 'XXXXX@gmail.com';
$email_subject = "New Price Match Request";
$email_body = "I display the html and data here";

//for attachments
//HOW DO I PULL THAT UPLOADED FILE FROM THE TEMP FOLDER AND SEND IT AS AN ATTACHMENT?
$attachments = (the file in temp folder);
//NOW HOW TO I DELETE IT FROM THE TEMP FOLDER

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n"; //$email is a SESSION variable pulled from before
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

//set to html
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));

//send
wp_mail( $to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers, $attachments );

// Reset content-type to avoid conflicts
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
```

I know a lot of the code it removed, but email works for all of the other information in the form being transferred by SESSION variables. I really just need to know how to transfer this uploaded file and email it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly...

For uploading file from temp folder use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) or [wp_handle_upload](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_upload/).

Then attach file to the mail `$attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file.txt' );`

Send mail and delete with [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

Comment: Good answer, short and sweet. I'm actually in the middle of trying this, fingers crossed.

Comment: Your answer works! Only problem now is I get an error: "_File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini._"  I've edited the php.ini file, made sure my folder permissions are correct, and have plenty of hard drive space. I can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Your solution works. I was able to finally send files. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use PHPMailer, its pretty easy and has a good documentation, sending an attachment is also easy with that.

Comment: Yea I've come across PHPMailer multiple times trying to figure this out. I tried it and hit another wall so I tried out wp_mail(). I was originally doing all of this with just mail() lol. I just hate to have to redo all of this when I'm so close.